# How can I show the Sales Report for particular user?

Tags: commerce

I use Drupal 7 and the [Drupal Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce) module.

My site has 3 roles defined:

1. **Admin**, who can publish and unpublish product of affiliate.
2. **Affiliate**, who can add the product in the site.
3. **Learner** who can see the show the all product and but the product.

My question is related to a learner buying a product which was added by an affiliate:

- When an affiliate checks the sales reports, then the report is null.
- But when an admin checks the sales reports, then it displays all functionality in the reports.
- And a learner can also check the sales reports.

So how can I solve these issues? Why are affiliate sales reports null?

Comment: Despite my accepted edit of the question, I still not understand the actual question for 100% (consider further editing it), i.e.: (a) Bullet "3." is still not clear and (b) I think the real (and only) question is like "Why does an affiliate get an empty report". Consider further editing your question to address these 2 items please.

Answer (score 0):

Attempt to answer the "Why does an affiliate get an empty report?" part of your question (which I believe is part of your question): could it be related to some "**permission**" you have not granted to an affiliate (yet)?

Here are a few links related to permissions that may be helpful:

- Drupal Commerce [issue nr 1303194](https://www.drupal.org/node/1303194).
- [What's the explanation for my product permission issue in a Drupal Commerce view?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/120526/) (and/or some of the "related" questions there).